# "Unindent does not match any outer indentation level" But I can't find any space or taberror

Tags: python, indentation

I get the error "unindent does not match any outer indentation level". However, when I google the issue, the answer is always that tabs and spaces were used interchangeably or something along those lines, but I can't find what could be wrong in my case. I have rewritten it, made sure everything was tabs, then rewrote it again, this time everything with spaces. I keep getting the error. Any help?

Note: the error shows up at the "if n == 2:" line

```
def is_prime_v3(n):
     '''return 'True' if 'n' is a prime number. False otherwise.'''
     if n == 1:
         return False

    #if the number is even and larger than 2, it is not a prime number.
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n>2 and n%2==0:
        return False    

    max_divisor = math.floor(math.sqrt(n))
    for d in range(3, 1+max_divisor,2):
        if n%d == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Which line is causing the issue?

Comment: the line: "if n == 2:"

Comment: *Show WhiteSpace* in text editors exists for a reason ...

Comment: For line indentation "yes". Not required aslong as there is minimum of 1 whitespace between a function/statement and variables/tasks (ifn==1 won't work but if n==1 does). Editors Jupyter, PyCharm or Komodo will help you spot them faster ;-)

Comment: @ZF007, I downloaded PyCharm and that helped with spotting the issues. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if n==1`, as well as the docstring, has one more space than `if n==2` and the rest of the code.

The sets them as "zero level" indentation inside the function, and the following code "un-indents" to less than zero.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was located between ''' return...snippet''' and `if n == 1:`. There was an unknown character that did something....

Try now:

```
import math

def is_prime_v3(n):
  X  '''return 'True' if 'n' is a prime number. False otherwise.'''
                         # whitespace too many at X.
  Y  if n == 1:          # whitespace too many at Y.
  Z      return False     # whitespace too many at Z.
    # if the number is even and larger than 2, it is not a prime number.
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n>2 and n%2==0:
        return False    

    max_divisor = math.floor(math.sqrt(n))

    for d in range(3, 1+max_divisor, 2):
        if n%d == 0:
            return False
    return True

print ('luck or lol : %s' % is_prime_v3(3))
```

EDIT: to be more specific, it looks like there was a:

> SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
>    with an  "EOF".

or

```
'''return 'True' if 'n' is a prime number. False otherwise.'''
```

> IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Of which the latter you might have fexed by now